# Filtering out columns from an R data.frame based on the sum of its values for all rows

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame` **df** where observations are cities and each column describes the amount of a certain pesticide used in that city (around 300 of them). The `data.frame` looks like this:

```
 head(df)
# A tibble: 6 x 11
  Benzovindiflupir Beta_ciflutrina Beta_Cipermetrina Bicarbonato_de_potássio Bifentrina Bispiribaque_sódi~ Bixafem Boscalida
             <dbl>           <dbl>             <dbl>                   <dbl>      <dbl>              <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>
1            0.354           1.10           0.0219                         0      4.99             0.0155  0.0686        0  
2           11.3             2.43           0.130                          0      8.84             0       2.08         22.2
3            0.329           0.267          0                              0      1.86             0.00746 0.00583       0  
4            4.56            2.71           0                              0      7.39             0       1.04          0  
5            0.925           0.512          0                              0      0.612            0       0.119         0  
6            0.388           0.149          0.000641                       0      1.61             0.143   0.0777        0
```

I would like to remove all pesticides (columns) whose sum of that pesticide use in all cities is below a threshold. I called this threshold `pestCutoff`.

```
pestCutoff <- 10000
```

So I want to create a new `data.frame` called **subDf** with all rows and only the columns whose sum of all rows is `>= cutoff`, but I haven`t found a way of filtering/subsetting/selecting columns based on a logical rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `select` with a condition on the `sum` i.e. if the `sum` of that column greater than threshold, then select it

```
library(dplyr)
subDf <- df %>%
    select(where( ~ sum(.) >= pestCutoff))
```

NOTE: Here we assume that the condition should be applied to all columns and all of them are numeric.  If there are other columns types and do not want to select, create a short circuit

```
subDf <- df %>%
          select(where(~ is.numeric(.) && sum(.) >= pestCutoff))
```

---

Or in `base R` with `Filter`

```
Filter(function(x) sum(x) >= pestCutoff, df)
```

Or with `colSums`

```
df[colSums(df) >= pestCutoff]
```

Answer (score 1):

We could also use `which(colSums)`

```
library(dplyr)
subDf <- df %>% select(which(colSums(.) >= pestCutoff))
```

data:

```
df <- tribble(
~Benzovindiflupir, ~Beta_ciflutrina, ~Beta_Cipermetrina, ~Bicarbonato_de_potássio, ~Bifentrina, ~Bispiribaque_sódi, ~Bixafem, ~Boscalida,
0.354, 1.10, 0.0219, 0, 4.99, 0.0155, 0.0686, 0, 
11.3, 2.43, 0.130, 0, 8.84, 0, 2.08, 22.2,
0.329, 0.267, 0, 0, 1.86, 0.00746, 0.00583, 0, 
4.56, 2.71, 0, 0, 7.39, 0, 1.04, 0, 
0.925, 0.512, 0, 0, 0.612, 0, 0.119, 0,
0.388, 0.149, 0.000641, 0, 1.61, 0.143, 0.0777, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

we may also use `select_if` with `sum` :

library(dplyr)

subDf <- df %>% select_if(~sum(.) >= pestCutoff)